# Memory Safety for same address: Int vs. Tuplet vs. Struct conflict

Tags: swift, memory

After reading the Memory Safety section of Swift Documentation, I came up with a question I cannot answer.

So I have the following code which is based on snippets from Swift's documentation:

```
func balance(_ x: inout Int, _ y: inout Int) {
    let sum = x + y
    x = sum / 2
    y = sum - x
}

struct Player {
    var name: String
    var health: Int
    var energy: Int    
}

// 1 - Memory Safety test for two different integers (just to see how this works)
var playerOneScore = 42
var playerTwoScore = 30
balance(&playerOneScore, &playerTwoScore)
print("Player 1 Balanced Score is: \(playerOneScore)")
print("Player 2 Balanced Score is: \(playerTwoScore)")

// 2 - Memory Safety test for the same two integers. COMPILE-TIME ERROR HERE.
balance(&playerOneScore, &playerOneScore)
print("Player 1 Balanced Score is: \(playerOneScore)")
print("Player 2 Balanced Score is: \(playerTwoScore)")

// 3 - Memory Safety test for the same property of a struct instance. THIS WORKS FINE.
var holly = Player(name: "Holly", health: 14, energy: 10)
balance(&holly.health, &holly.health) 
print("Holly's Balanced Health is \(holly.health)")

// 4 - Memory Safety test for the same property of a tuple. THIS ALSO WORKS FINE.
var playerInformation = (health: 10, energy: 20)
balance(&playerInformation.health, &playerInformation.health)
print("Health is: \(playerInformation.health)")
print("Energy is: \(playerInformation.energy)")
```

So, from the documentation I understand the error from section 2 in this code because I would be writing the same location in memory twice.
The problem arises for section 3 and 4. It seems that I should be getting the same error as in section 2, because in both cases I would also be accessing the same address in memory. What I am missing here?

Additionally, the documentation says that code similar to the one in section 4 in my code should produce an error. Original code from documentation as follows:

```
var playerInformation = (health: 10, energy: 20)
balance(&playerInformation.health, &playerInformation.energy)
// Error: conflicting access to properties of playerInformation
```

Finally, section 3 of my code should produce an error and, according to Apple, the way to solve that error is to make it a local variable. Original code from documentation as follows:

```
var holly = Player(name: "Holly", health: 10, energy: 10)
balance(&holly.health, &holly.energy)  // Error

func someFunction() {
    var oscar = Player(name: "Oscar", health: 10, energy: 10)
    balance(&oscar.health, &oscar.energy)  // OK
    }
```

So, summing up, the questions are:

A) why section 2 in my code works while section 3 and 4 don't?

B) why errors in the snippets from Apple's documentation do not actually create errors in the compilers and actually work?

Thanks!

Comment: Which Xcode version are you using? I get compiler errors for section 2, 3, and 4 in Xcode 10.1.

Comment: @MartinR I got compiler error only for section 2 in Xcode 10.1 (Swift console app).

Comment: Oh, it seems there is a setting in Xcode (
"Swift Compiler - Code Generation" -> "Exclusive Access to Memory") which makes the difference. It seems "Compile time enforcement" fails to compile section 2 while "Full enforcement (Runtime checks)" fails to compile all. I smell some bug here.